# Searching Arrays using Recursion?

Tags: java, file, recursion, arraylist, directory

Does someone know how to use recursion to search for Arrays of objects inside other Arrays?
Carpetas = Folders  Archivos = Files  Nombre = Name  Tamaño = Size

Edit: Translated a few souts for furthe clarity.

The point of this exercise is to create ArrayLists inside of other ArrayLists, simulating real folders and Files used in computers. The code below is what I have done so far.   Help!

```
public class Carpetas {

private String nombre;
private int tamaño;
ArrayList <Carpetas> Crp;
ArrayList <Archivo> Arc;



public Carpetas(String nombre, int tamaño){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tamaño = tamaño;
    Crp = null;
    Arc = null;
}

public ArrayList<Carpetas> getCrp() {
    return Crp;
}

public void setCrp(Carpetas nueva_carpeta) {
    if(Crp == null){
       Crp = new ArrayList<>(); 
       Crp.add(nueva_carpeta);
    }else{
       Crp.add(nueva_carpeta); 
    }
}

public ArrayList<Archivo> getArc() {
    return Arc;
}

public void setArc(Archivo nuevo_archivo ) {
    if(Arc == null)
    {
        Arc = new ArrayList<>();
        Arc.add(nuevo_archivo);
    }else
    {
        Arc.add(nuevo_archivo);
    }
}



public static void menu(int a){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1 - Search folder: ");
    System.out.println("2 - Type in/Create Folder: ");
    System.out.println("3 - Type in/Create Files: ");
    System.out.println("Typ in the menu option: ");
    a = input.nextInt();
    switch(a){
        case 1:



            break;
    }
}

public String searchCarpeta(String nombre, int y){
    if(y == Crp.size()){
        return "File not found.";
    }
    if(nombre.equals(Crp.get(y).getNombre())){
        return Crp.get(y).getNombre();
    }
    else{
        return searchCarpeta(nombre, y++);
    }        
}

public void createCarpetas(String nombre, int y){
    if(nombre.equals(Crp.get(y).getNombre())){
        System.out.println("Folder already exists.");
        return;
    }
    else{
       Crp.add(new Carpetas(nombre, 0));
        System.out.println("Folder added successfully!");
    }

}

public void createArchivo(String nombre, String archivo, int y){

}


public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public int getTamaño() {
    return tamaño;
}

public void setTamaño(int tamaño) {
    this.tamaño = tamaño;
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Carpetas crp = null;

    System.out.println("Type the name of the file: ");
    String nombre = input.next();

    crp.Crp.add(new Carpetas(nombre, 0));

}
```

}

Comment: It will be useful if methods and messages in ``sout`` were in english. At least it will give a hint, cause you didn't mention many ...

Comment: Or at least comments describing what everything does

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Pollo_H:A piece of code is written once but read many times by lots of people. Please take that seriously into account before writing code using your native language everywhere. Otherwise what is the difference for someone reading `if(nombre.equals(Crp.get(y).getNombre())){` with `if(a1.equals(X.get(y).geta1())){`